# Git submodule completely refusing to cooperate

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have two repositories. BigRepo and SmallRepo.

I want to make the SmallRepo a submodule of BigRepo.

What I did?

I First cloned BigRepo.

Then I ran

`git submodule add git://github.com/Karlovsky120/SmallRepo.git submodules\SmallRepo`

which successfully cloned the SmallRepo into BigRepo.

Now I ran `git status` and got:

```
new file: .gitmodules
new file: submodules/SmallRepo
```

If I run `git submodule init` it fails with the message:

`fatal: No url found for submodule path 'submodules/SmallRepo' in .gitmodules`

(I know it's already initialized, but the url is RIGHT THERE).

I also tried committing and pushing the changes and then deleting the local repo to clone it again, but it would fail with the same message.

I know that when I pushed the changes, the submodule appeared in the web interface, but I could not click it. I don't know if that's normal behavior.

I've looked up (and followed) a bunch of tutorials, but I have no idea why this is happening. It's supposed to be super simple, yet the most basic example is failing.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

Contents of .gitmodules is:

```
[submodule "submodules\\SmallRepo"]
    path = submodules\\SmallRepo
    url = git://github.com/Karlovsky120/SmallRepo.git
```

Comment: What is the output of the 'cat .gitmodules'

Comment: I'm guessing you want the contents? See edit. (cat is not a recognized command on my Windows PC)

Comment: I followed your steps, no issue for me. Seems windows-specific?

Comment: open git bash and cat the file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have path restriction, then the following should do the job:

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/chenrui333/config-repo.git SmallRepo
$ git submodule init


$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "SmallRepo"]
    path = SmallRepo
    url = git://github.com/chenrui333/config-repo.git

$ ls SmallRepo/
README.md test
```

I just used one-level path, which I think it may be the cause.

**[UPDATE]**

Turns out it is the path issue, update with modified scripts:

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/chenrui333/config-repo.git SmallRepo/config
$ git submodule init


$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "SmallRepo/config"]
    path = SmallRepo/config
    url = git://github.com/chenrui333/config-repo.git

$ ls SmallRepo/config/
README.md test
```

Comment: It wasn't, but it gave me an idea. It seems that I was using the wrong slash -> `\\`` instead of `/`

Comment: after second look at your question, yes, this should be `submodules\\SmallRepo` instead of `submodules\SmallRepo` in windows context

Comment: That, or a slash in the other direction.